# Inbox and Fluid - Compose mail with google scripts

Tags: javascript, fluid-mac-app-engine, google-inbox

I am new to Inbox and would like know if there is a way to use Inbox with googlescript/javascript.

The reason is, that I am using Inbox on OSX with fluid. Fluid allows me use the Inbox web version as a standalone program. The only problem I have until now is opening 'mailto:*' links on the web. With gmail it works, I simply have to add a script which does the following

```
function transform(inURLString) {
return 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=' + inURLString;
}
```

Problem is, that this of course opens a 'Compose mail' window for gmail. Instead I would like to open the compose mail dialog in Inbox, which then should include the address of the recipient, given by inURLString.

Hope someone can help me or send me a link to a site which is fit for this question :-)